# showing a FragmmentDialog from calls that extends View class

Tags: android, fragment, android-dialogfragment

I have an activity which is called `MainPage` and it extends `SherlockFragmentActivity`.
This activity has tabs, each tab shows different fragment. One of the fragments displays a `SaleRow` view which is a custom view (class that extends the `RelativeLayout` class). Also I have `SaleDialog` class which extends `DialogFragment`. What I am trying to do is to show the SaleDialog from the `SaleRow` view class. I tried to use this code:

```
public class SaleRow extends RelativeLayout 
{   
    public SaleRow(Context context) 
    {
        super(context);

        ...

        this.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) 
            {
            FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager(); //compilation error here for getFragmentManager The method getFragmentManager() is undefined for the type new View.OnClickListener()
                SaleDialog testDialog = new SaleDialog();
                testDialog.setRetainInstance(true);
                testDialog.show(fm, "fragment_name");
            }

        });
```

I have search for a solution but couldn't find something relevant.

Thaks

Comment: getting this error" `Type mismatch: cannot convert from android.app.FragmentManager to android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager`

Comment: I am importing `import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try keeping a reference to your `context` object, cast it and then call `getSupportFragmentManager` on it:

```
public class SaleRow extends RelativeLayout 
{
    private Context mContext;
    public SaleRow(Context context) 
    {
        super(context);
        mContext = context;
        this.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) 
            {
                try{
                    FragmentManager fm = ((FragmentActivity) mContext).getSupportFragmentManager();
                } catch (ClassCastException e) {
                   Log.d(TAG, "Can't get fragment manager frmom context");
                }
                SaleDialog testDialog = new SaleDialog();
                testDialog.setRetainInstance(true);
                testDialog.show(fm, "fragment_name");
            }

        });
    }
}
```

Comment: did as you suggested and getting this compilation error: `Description Resource Path Location Type
The method getFragmentManager() is undefined for the type Context`

Comment: ok try my edited answer, in order to work, your Activity must `extend FragmentActivity`

Comment: now I am getting this`'Type mismatch: cannot convert from Activity to FragmentManager` on this line: `FragmentManager fm = (Activity) mContext;`

Comment: sorry I forgot something last time

Comment: now I am getting this error: `Type mismatch: cannot convert from android.app.FragmentManager to android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager`

Comment: my activity is extending `SherlockFragmentActivity`. and I create the SaleRow from `SherlockFragment` like this: `SaleRow saleRow = new SaleRow(getActivity());`

Comment: SherlockFragmentActivity extends FragmentActivity so the casting should be fine. When using a compatibility Activity such as FragmentActivity, you need to get the support FragmentManager via getSupportFragmentManager()

Answer (score 0):

try `SomeActivity.getFragmentManager();`

Comment: I tried to get the activity from the context and then do as you preposed, it didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

Trying to affect the state of the fragment manager from a view is a bad idea in my opinion. What I prefer to do is only allow the parent `Activity` to manipulate the fragment manager. This way, the view is decoupled from the activity, and the activity can decide what it wants to do and how it wants to do it. So I would listen for the click event in the `Fragment`, then pass that event up to the parent `Activity` with a callback interface:

The following goes in the `Fragment` that has the `SaleRow`:

```
// Step 1 - Create callback interface
Callback mCallback;

public interface Callback {

    public void showSaleDialog();
}

// Step 2 - Cast the parent Activity to the callback
@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {

    try {
        mCallback = (Callback) activity;
    }
    catch (ClassCastException e) {
        throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString() + " must implement Callback");
    }
}

// Step 3 - Set the listener on the SaleRow in the onCreateView() class
saleRow.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View v) {

        // Step 4 - call showSaleDialog() using the callback
        mCallback.showSaleDialog();
    }
});
```

And then in the `Activity`:

```
public class MyActivity extends SherlockFragmentActivity implements Callback {

    @Override
    public void showSaleDialog() {

        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        SaleDialog testDialog = new SaleDialog();
        testDialog.setRetainInstance(true);
        testDialog.show(fm, "fragment_name");
    }
```